# Is it possible to see active connections in nginx?

Tags: nginx, connection

Is it possible to see what URLs are actively being served by nginx (i.e., see the URLs that are in the middle of being responded to, not the ones that nginx has finished responding to).

I would like to see these because I am using the [nginx push module](https://github.com/slact/nginx_http_push_module) and am trying to figure out why the number of active (and write) connections rises all the time. These are requests that are held open a long time, so I'd like to be able to see what URLs are being handled by nginx at the moment, and ideally also some information about those clients (i.e. user-agent, ip address, would all be helpful).

Comment: I don't know of any way for nginx to do this natively. However, one way you could get this data is to put a proxy like Varnish in front of nginx (but disable the caching part of Varnish - since that isn't your goal). Varnish can display all the requests going to your backend (nginx) in real time, and the responses received from the backend - it also provides full headers, IP, etc. Not ideal, but perhaps an option if you don't get other suggestions.

Comment: Open a feature request in nginx's Trac: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/

Comment: do they write and active connection are growing on a similar pattern? if active is big and not write it may just be the keep-alive connections http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpStubStatusModule

Answer (score 2):

There's an [extended status module](http://wiki.nginx.org/Extended_status_module) (patch) as 3rd party module, I think it'd do it.